# Autoincrementing column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment

I'm trying to create a table where one of the columns will contain autoincrementing numbers. Is there some other way of doing that instead of creating sequence for each row? The rows will be dynamically added/removed and the sequence needs to be resetable.

Table should look like this:

```
[Foreign_Key]   [Sequence_State]
    A               0
    B               0
    C               0
```

And when I call something like this(pseudocode):

```
getNextNumber('A');
getNextNumber('A');
getNextNumber('A');
getNextNumber('B');
getNextNumber('B');
```

the state of the table should change to this:

```
[Foreign_Key]   [Sequence_State]
    A               3
    B               2
    C               0
```

I guess I could go with PL/SQL function which would create the sequence for the `Foreign_Key` if it doesn't exist, increment and update the `Sequence_State`. But this all seems a bit clunky and I'm wondering if there's some better way to do that.

Comment: what bout a trigger? like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388576/oracle-auto-increment-trigger

Comment: But I would need to have this trigger before select(which I think doesn't exist in Oracle). The sequences need to be created on the fly, because rows can change.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean "creating sequence for each row"?  Your sample data doesn't look like it has an auto-incremented anything in it.  Can you clarify the question by providing sample data, before and after the update?

Comment: Why do they need to change?  are you looking at a 'Sequence' for the rows returned in a select?

Comment: I've updated the question. It should behave like if every record in the table had independent sequence. If the rows were static, then I would simply create sequence for each row, but it will change. For example by some user action, a new record 'D' will appear. Right now I'm trying to put together some function using execute immediate to create and increment sequences on the fly

Comment: You will need an update statement for that.  That is not what sequences are for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. As bowlturner pointed out, sequences aren't necessary(although I tried that they could be used). Simple selects and updates are enough:

```
create or replace function getNextNumber(otherid IN VARCHAR2)
return number
is 
  nextval NUMBER;
  entryexists NUMBER(1);
begin
  select case
    when exists(select * from CURRENT_STATE where OTHER_ID=otherid)
      then 1
      else 0
    end into entryexists
  from dual;  
  if entryexists = 0
    then      
      insert into CURRENT_STATE (OTHER_ID, SEQUENCE_STATE) values (otherid, 1);
      nextval := 1;
    else  
      update CURRENT_STATE set SEQUENCE_STATE = SEQUENCE_STATE + 1 where     OTHER_ID=otherid
        RETURNING SEQUENCE_STATE into nextval;
  end if;
  return nextval;
end;
/
```

Comment: Remember about concurrency issues when more than one session runs this simultaneously...

Comment: I think the only problem is when creating new record(which shouldn't happen so often). The increment using ```UPDATE...RETURNING``` should be atomic I think. Is that right?

Comment: Right. You could also prepopulate the table with all values you need and leave just the update in the procedure.