# Auto-Generated numbers in SQL for one of the Attributes(should be supported by Oracle 10g/11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can anyone help me to auto-generate the empID field,                                            so that we don't enter the value through the insert statement.                                                                             `create table employee( empID int,designation varchar(10));`                                     What shall be the code so that I enter only designation and ename but not empID (which should be automatically generated)?

Comment: This question seems to have been answered several times. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sequences](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php). I have used this and they work great.