# ActiveRecord destroy_all throws StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord with oracle adapter on Ruby on Rails. I am getting a `StatementInvalid Exception` when trying to delete a row.

Here is how my table looks like : **room_user_table**

```
room | user
1010 | a
1010 | b
1011 | a
1011 | c
1011 | d
```

My ruby ActiveRecord class:

```
class RoomUserTable < ActiveRecord:Base
    self.table_name = 'room_user_table'
end
```

Now I want to delete the 2nd row for example, so I am issuing

```
RoomUserTable.destroy_all(:room => 1010, :user => 'b')
```

But this is throwing ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception

```
OCIError: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier: DELETE FROM "ROOM_USER_TABLE" WHERE "ROOM_USER_TABLE"."" = :a1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

My test_controller.rb

```
class TestController < ActionController::Base
    def test
       RoomUserTable.destroy_all(:room => 1010, :user => 'b')
    end
end
```

Comment: RoomUserTable.where(:room => 1010, :user => 'b').first.destroy

Comment: This is throwing the same exception `ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RoomUserTable` doesn't have a primary key, which is causing it to run the query that you have in your question `WHERE "ROOM_USER_TABLE"."" = ...` which in turn is causing Oracle to throw a wobbly. Rails models need to have primary keys.

The table looks like a join table therefore you don't need to create a model for it or query it directly at all. You can use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `User` and `Room` and specify the join table.

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :room_user_table
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms, join_table: :room_user_table
end
```

Or similar.

Edit - having said that you have `a`, `b` etc in your user column, so I've no idea what that table is, but the problem is still the same, you don't have a primary key.

Comment: Actually room_user_table had a composite primary key (user, room) which doesn't have a build-in support in ror. I am trying to install http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/ to overcome this

Comment: For some reason, compositekeys plugin didn't worked for me. So I created an additional ID column as primary key set to auto_increment following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle Now everything works fine. Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

To delete a simgle record you should do

```
RoomUserTable.where(:room => 1010, :user => 'b').first.destroy
```

The reason I suggest that is because it is safer than destroy_all, but makes sense only when you are trying to remove a single record.

The best would be to find a record by id of course.

This also should work, but given your problem I'm not sure.

```
RoomUserTable.where(:room => 1010, :user => 'b').destroy_all
```

Comment: I tried that too I got `ArgumentError` : `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` I not sure why am I getting that

Comment: Maybe try with old hash notation? Can you paste traceback of this ArgumentError somewhere (pastie.org)?

Comment: ah, I'm a moron! See this guys comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720312/activerecord-destroy-all-throws-statementinvalid/17720371?noredirect=1#comment25828655_17720312

Comment: `RoomUserTable.where(:room => 1010, :user => 'b').destroy_all` is also throwing the same Exception `ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier`

Comment: require 'RoomUserTable'
class TestController < ActionController::Base
    def test
       ...
    end
end

Comment: Why do you do the require? It is a AR class, not a lib! Remove require form the first line.

Comment: Other ActiveRecord methods are working fine like find(), where(), delete() etc. Only destroy() is causing trouble

Comment: That doesn't mean you should have this require!

Comment: I have removed the 'require' but still getting same error, but anyway thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RoomUserTable.where(:room => 1010, :user => 'b').first.destroy
```

Comment: This is throwing the same exception `ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier`