# create auto increment id in preparedstatement

Tags: java, oracle

i want to create auto increment id using preparedstatement, i'm using oracle database and this is my code

```
public Client newClient(Client client){
        try {
            con = DBConnection.getConnection(driver, url, name, pass);      
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CLIENT (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CAREER, CSALARY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.setString(1, client.getFirstName());
            pstmt.setString(2, client.getLastName());
            pstmt.setString(3, client.getCareer());
            pstmt.setInt(4, client.getcSalary());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();      
            rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
             rs.next();

            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            client.setcId(id);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }finally{
        try{ rs.close(); }catch (Exception e){}
        try{ pstmt.close();}catch (Exception e){}
        try{ con.close();}catch (Exception e){}
    }//finally
    return client;
}`
```

but i have this error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AHMAD"."CLIENT"."CID")
```

plz help me

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle does not have anything called auto_increment. If you are using sequence, you have to explicitly set sequence.nextval to the key else use trigger to update the column.

Comment: You will need to create a trigger to take care of the auto ID generation.

Comment: thank you alot for your reply but can you give me example cuz i try using seq.nextval but i have the same error

Comment: Please post the SQL used to create your table(s). Otherwise people have to guess.

Comment: @Ahmad What is `CID`? Is it a column of table CLIENT?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: yes cid it client id it is PK column in client table

Comment: @Ahmad Then have a look at the link provided by Gyro...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need an [autonumber sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)

> To retrieve the next value in the sequence order, you need to use
>   nextval.
>
> For example:
>
> supplier_seq.nextval

and that will provide an autoincremented sequence id for your `INSERT` (i.e. you simply perform the `INSERT` and the db will insert the autoincremented value)