# sql error : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

this is my code. but i don't know where is the mistakes since i used 11g express edition. it shows error but no show which line the error

```
CREATE TABLE hsstaff
(
staff_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
staff_name varchar(50),
staff_address varchar(50),
staff_position varchar(20),
staff_telno varchar(15),
access_level varchar(15),
password varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (staff_ID)
);
```

Comment: My oracle knowledge is a bit lacking, but I'm pretty sure the issue is using `AUTO_INCREMENT` - Oracle uses sequences that you have to define/create.

Comment: See: [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: There is no such thing as auto_increment in oracle. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AUTO_INCREMENT`; this is not supported in Oracle.

Comment: YES, it's not support in 11g. You can only use sequences and constraint to achieve this.