# How to avoid inserting null values into Primary key or Not Null columns?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am inserting into a table from my jdbc program, 
like this

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlqry);
        ps.setInt(1,dto.getInstall_id());
        ps.setString(2, dto.getDashboard_name());
        ps.setString(3, dto.getDashboard_type());
        ps.setString(4, dto.getDashboard_image());
```

But in the table i have column say **D_ID** which in is primary key and i dont want o insert the **D_ID** from my program into table because the same id might be already exist. So for avoiding the PK_CONSTRAINT I am not inseting it.
But when i try this i am getting this error.

```
 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TESTDB"."TESTATBLE"."D_ID")
```

So how can i solve this problem, Any alternative like if i insert D_ID from the program my JDBC program the **D_ID** column should dynamically generate id's in the table.
I am banging my head for this. Please help!

Comment: can you the string sqlqry? And also the coulmn names

Comment: Have you made "Auto Increment" true for your database? If yes, then you need not insert id into table, DB will take care automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create that ID using a sequence. So for each ID column that you have, you create a corresponding sequence:

```
create table testatble 
(
  d_id integer not null primary key,
  install_id integer not null,
  dashboard_name varchar(100)
  ... more columns ....
);

create sequence seq_testatble_d_id;
```

You can use it like this:

```
// note that there is no placeholder for the D_ID column
// the value is taken directly from the sequence
String sqlqry = 
"insert into testatble (d_id, install_id, dashboard_name)  " + 
"values (seq_testatble_d_id.nextval, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlqry);
ps.setInt(1,dto.getInstall_id());
ps.setString(2, dto.getDashboard_name());
... more parameters ...
ps.executeUpdate();
```

That way the id will be generated automatically.

If you need the generated ID in your Java code after the insert, you can use `getGeneratedKeys()` to return it:

```
// the second parameter tells the driver 
// that you want the generated value for the column D_ID
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlqry, new String[]{"D_ID"});

// as before
ps.setInt(1,dto.getInstall_id());
ps.setString(2, dto.getDashboard_name());
... more parameters ...
ps.executeUpdate();

// now retrieve the generated ID
int d_id = -1;
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) // important!
{
   d_id = rs.getInt(1);
}
rs.close();
```

More on sequences in the Oracle manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253

Comment: Thanx A lot for the usefull information with such a easy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Auto Increment number for ID(I Oracle you can use sequence). You can do this at the link:

[Create ID with auto increment on oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

You should also read this. If there is a sequence to your ID then [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) you can read information about that.