# Auto Incremant composite key Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence, auto-generate

How to have multiple sequences depending on the value of specific column in `Oracle`; that is, new `Sequence` for each different value for that column.

Table is:

```
  CREATE TABLE TEST 
     (
      TYPE VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ,
      SERIAL_NUM INT NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY 
      (
        TYPE,
       SERIAL_NUM 
      )
      ENABLE 
    );
```

This Link: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

shows how to generate auto incremental `Sequence` assuming that the primary key is one attribute. **How to have separate `Sequence` for each unique value in `TYPE` column?**

I was thinking of creating multiple `Sequences` for each possible value in `TYPE`, creating `Trigger` for each `Sequence` and adding `if`condition for flirting based on `TYPE` column value. But, I realized that this is not the right approach since I need to create new `Sequence` and `Trigger` for any new `TYPE` added.

A sample data should be similar to the following:

```
TYPE    SERIAL_NUM
X             1
X             2
X             3
Y             1
Y             2
Z             1
Z             2
Z             3
Z             4
```

Any suggestions...

Comment: What prevents you from using a single sequence for all types?

Comment: What is the business problem that you want to solve?  Why do you have a requirement that there must a a row where the `serial_num` is 1 for `type` A and then another row with a `serial_num` of 1 for `type` B?  What problem do you get from having the `serial_num` values be unique?  Hopefully, you're not trying to create a gap-free set of values...

Comment: Actually, nothing prevents me to have unique serial number for each item. I was asking if that possible. Also, what make me think of that is that I have the`TYPE`column which is part of the primary key and I thought that data will be more organized and easier to go through @FrankSchmitt @JustinCave

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality in Oracle for this.

Solution 1.

Create a sequence for each type. If new types can be added in run-time then you need to do DDL in run-time (using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE). If there are many types you will get many sequences.

Solution 2.

Implement your own sequence-like functionality in a separate table with one row for each type to keep track of the next value. Be sure to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and in general be mindful of concurrency issues if going with this option.

```
CREATE TABLE PseudoSequence (
  TYPE    VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  SEQ_NO  INT NOT NULL
);
```

Note that option 1 is more scalable with regard to concurrent insertions of records of the same type.