# sql table creation using command

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

```
create table participants (
partid number(19) not null primary key auto_increment,
partmn varchar(20) null,
partln varchar(20) null
)
```

when I am running this code in Oracle it is giving ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis this error after removing auto_increment it is working

Comment: Oracle doesn't have auto-increment attribute. However, you can attain the same functionality through sequences.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "auto_increment" or "identity" columns in Oracle. However, you can achive it easily with a sequence.

and after oracle 12 , identity is supported but not auto increment.

use below lines

```
ALTER TABLE participants ADD (
  CONSTRAINT partid_pk PRIMARY KEY (partid));

CREATE SEQUENCE party_seq;

Trigger definition:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER party 
BEFORE INSERT ON participants
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT party_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.partid
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

for oracle 12 and above you can use without triggers like below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE participants_seq;
CREATE TABLE participants (
  partyId          NUMBER DEFAULT participants _seq.NEXTVAL,
  other column definitions
);
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i do this??

Comment: "There is no concept of "identity" columns in Oracle*" - actually there is since 12c: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17906/chapter1.htm#NEWFT158

Comment: can you please observe this below line in the post which i had answered..after oracle 12 , identity is supported but not auto increment...