# create unique numerical identifier column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a list of states.  I did this to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE drb (
  Statename VARCHAR2(15)
)
```

I then inserted the state data.  However, I want my first column to be a created unique state ID.  So it should list 1-50 for the 50 states in the United States.  I tried searching different unique tutorials [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)   and nothing seemed to work.

Essentially, I want to know how to get a unique numerical key for a variable

Comment: `Id int not null auto increment`

Comment: You've tagged this for MySQL and Oracle-- two completely different database systems with different SQL dialects.  Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: hey guys - i'm a beginner at sql.  i've gotten good at other languages by teachign myself and asking questions after i feel i've searched my hardest.  i put in my post where i searched and i wasn't finding quite what i was looking for.  so i went here for help.  no reason to downvote, i'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table should have id field along with statename, add it this way.

```
CREATE TABLE drb (
  id NUMBER,
  Statename VARCHAR2(15)
);
```

Make `id` as `primary key`:

```
alter table drb
add constraint drb_pk primary key (id);
```

Create a sequence as follows:

```
create ore replace sequence drb_sequence
 start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Create a trigger which will insert a unique id into `drb` table as follows:

```
create or replace trigger drb_trigger
before insert on drb
for each row
begin
select drb_sequence.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
/
```

Now insert into `drb`:

```
insert into drb(Statename) values('state one');
```

Select from `drb`:

```
select * from drb;
```

**Output :**

```
--------------------------
|id          Statename   |
--------------------------
|1           state one   |
--------------------------
```

Hope it helps.