# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on create table query

Tags: oracle

I never liked the error/debug data oracle returns. They are not telling me on what line I did what wrong or they couldn't compile/execute what.

I really can't see what I am doing wrong with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE grad_candidates
(
student_id NUMBER(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
credits NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
graduation_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)
```

I am using the oracle apex (https://iacademy.oracle.com/) for testing

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: @Mat Thanks! Solved it! Please use an answer instead of comment so i will 'like' it :P

Comment: "*I never liked the error/debug data oracle returns*" - then you are using the wrong tools. SQL*Plus for example will indicate precisely at which position the error occurred

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using the oracle apex because the tables  I need for homework/studies are in there. And there is no option to export. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Ismail _"I am using the oracle apex [...] And there is no option to export."_ There is nothing to "export". Apex is backed up by an Oracle DB -- and so you can use SQL*Plus to interact with your DB "out of the box".