# Entity Framework with Oracle - Auto-increment Sequence Without Trigger

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, sequence, interceptor

Is there any way to solve the .Net Entity Framework Oracle PL/SQL Sequence issue without trigger, while inserting data ? Interceptor should be a method for this but which way do you suggest?
Thnx.

Comment: what "Oracle PL/SQL Sequence issue " are you talking about?

Comment: select nextval from sequence before inserting the entity

Comment: Why the -1 vote?  This is a very important question for Oracle users since it is the only database that 'requires' you to setup the auto-incrementing sequence for 'Identity' fields.  I would like to see an Oracle DBA/programmer answer this question...

Comment: Oracle 12c supports auto incrementing sequences . Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle#answer-24222811

Comment: Yep, Oracle 12c solves this problem but it seems using trigger is the single way to solve this problem on 11g. @Ovidiu if you can post your comment as a answer I will check solved this question, however it doesn't meet my expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 12c adds support for autoincrementing sequences :
[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle#answer-24222811)

Until then there is not much to do but to use triggers . I have a sample project with ef 6 and oracle 11g only with nuget packages(works also in linux), check out my answer from this question:

[Entity framework connection with oracle databse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969699/entity-framework-connection-with-oracle-databse/30117245#30117245)