# Entity framework connection with oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity framework 6.1 version and oracle 11.
I am new to entity framework.
Can anyone please suggest what are the prerequisites for connecting with oracle.
any changes are required in the web.config.
In web.config,default it is connecting with sql,how can i change it to use Oracle instead of sql.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2472399? http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm?

Comment: If you used NuGet, it should modify your web/app config for you.  Also, since the EF version is another common gotcha, if you uninstall EF, the NuGet package for the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework will download the version it's compatible with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a sample project with EF 6 and oracle 11g which **only uses nuget packages**:

https://github.com/ovidiubuligan/EntityFramework_Oracle_sample

The most important parts are **App.config** and **packages.config**.

If you look in App.config you will see that it will use the connection string :
`connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=...` instead of a **tns file** http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora . I find it more confortable.

Comment: Thanks for the link.it is working with some changes.