# Executing Auto Increment Query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

> Error starting at line 1 in command: CREATE TABLE Persons ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID) ) Error at Command Line:3 Column:17 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" *Cause:     *Action:

Comment: Error seems like an Oracle DB? Is it right?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any other alternative. I tried with checking out if in the UI i had any feature to add the auto increment condition. But, i was unable to find one

Comment: I think you are missing a semicolon

Comment: Yes @Tobi but i'm unable to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If its Oracle, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: Still the same.. and it doesn't matter about semicolon if its a single query right?

Comment: In Oracle12 you can use an identity column: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, there is no `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Try the solution in [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-%20auto-increment-on-oracle) to trigger an auto increment: