# SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword when create identity column based table

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c

I try to create an auto incremented column on a table and as I see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle) there are 2 ways, the second implementation with the Identity column is a more elegant solution, but when I try to implement it I get the following error:

```
    Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 31
    Error report -
    SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword
    02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
```

Actual table script implementation:

```
CREATE TABLE "PLATFORM"."AUTH_PERMISSION"
(
    ID NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, 
    -- ID NUMBER(19,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ACTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    RESOURCE_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    ENVIRONMENT_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "ACTION_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ACTION_ID")
      REFERENCES "AUTH_ACTION" ("ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "ENVIRONMENT_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ENVIRONMENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "AUTH_ENVIRONMENT" ("ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "RESOURCE_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("RESOURCE_ID")
      REFERENCES "AUTH_RESOURCE" ("ID") ENABLE,
    UNIQUE (ACTION_ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, RESOURCE_ID)
);
```

It can bee seen that the column that I try to auto-increment is the primary key of the table.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109) is the reference from where I got the solution.

The problem was that I used an older version of Oracle, 11g.

Comment: `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` statement is a void. check out more information here http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php . It exists from oracle 12c, specify your database version??

Comment: your oracle version??

Comment: the oracle version is 12c

Comment: Are you sure the server is 12c, not just your client? It looks very much like your server is 11g. What does `select * from product_component_version` or `select * from v$version` report?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps the Oracle database **(server)** you are trying to connect to is **12c**, however the client **(installed locally)** you are using doesn't support the feature. Please check your **Oracle client version**, it could be **11g or lower** which doesn't support it. You need to download a higher client version.

Works perfectly on version **12.1.0.1**.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> CREATE TABLE AUTH_PERMISSION
  2  (
  3      ID NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  4      -- ID NUMBER(19,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  5      NAME VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  6      ACTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  7      RESOURCE_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  8      ENVIRONMENT_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL
  9  );

Table created.
```

Comment: Oracle 11 gives error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword

Comment: Perhaps you are using a 11g client version which doesn't support it. You need download a higher client version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are run into this issue, and you can't update the database/client from 11 to 12 then here is the workaround.

1. Add the following line of code to your Dbcontext Class`

```
optionsBuilder.UseOracle(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b =>
            b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));
```

**Explanation:** Oracle 11g do not support IDENTITY command. The PKs must be generated with a trigger and a sequence. When you add ***UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11")*** to the DbContext, EF will generate migrations scripts compatible with oracle 11g. In this case, A sequence table will be generated to use for the PKS.

2. Another issue you might run into is this:
   **ORA-00972: identifier is too long**

If you run into this error, it means oracle database versions less than 12 only support identifiers of max length 30.

**Solution:**

1. For Dotnet Core below 3.1 use add this to your DBContext class

`modelBuilder.Model.Relational().MaxIdentifierLength = 30;`

2. For Dotnet Core 3.1 above, use this instead.

`modelBuilder.Model.SetMaxIdentifierLength(30);`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error but when I tried running as script in editor, it worked. I later pasted in .sql file to run the script as `@<path>\<filename>`

code:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING(
  ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20)
  );
```

This worked for me. I am using
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64 bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0

you may also try:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING(
  ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(START WITH 101 MAXVALUE 9999999 
       MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE CACHE 20) NOT NULL, 
  NAME VARCHAR2(20)
  );
```

start with : is from where you want to start your counter (I used 101)
maxvalue is till what value it should increment
minvalue is increment by
nocycle cashe is how many numbers u want to keep in ram