# Have Identity Columns been removed in Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, identity-column

I'm able to create the following table in my environment. However, in our QA environment, it fails with the following error:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
```

Originally, we got the error described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806412/sql-error-ora-02000-missing-always-keyword-when-create-identity-column-based-t) until I changed:

```
GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

To:

```
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

Here's the code, and specifications:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
ID NUMBER(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);
```

**My Environment: (Working)**

- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit
- PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0
- CORE 12.1.0.1.0
- TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0
- NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0

**QA Environment: (Failing)**

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

- PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0
- CORE 12.1.0.2.0
- TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0
- NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: I was facing same issue, refer my answer in [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806412/sql-error-ora-02000-missing-always-keyword-when-create-identity-column-based-t/66715954#66715954)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they haven't been removed.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
(
  ID_COL_PK NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1      START WITH 1 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 2000 ORDER NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT TABLE1_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ID_COL_PK 
  )
  ENABLE 
);
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC)

Comment: Thanks. We've done some testing and haven't been able to deduce why these tables failed on the initial run. They're all working now. No changes to the environment.