# django migrating from sqlite3 to oracle causes ora-2000 error

Tags: python, django, oracle

I hava a Django app on a windows server 2012 which was set up with sqlite3 as the db, but it's going to production so I'm migrating the tables to oracle 11g on the server, i don't care about the data just the tables so when I run

```
    python manage.py migrate
```

I get ORA-2000 Error: missing ALWAYS keyword

I'm new to django and websites in general, what am i missing?

Database setting:

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME':     'orcl',
    'USER':     'hr',
    'PASSWORD': 'hr',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '1521',
       },
   'OPTIONS': {
    'timeout': 20,
    'threaded': True,
}}
```

Model:

```
class ForecastSummary(models.Model):


party=models.ForeignKey(PartyDetailsFinal,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
annual_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                   null=True)
annual_HW = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                null=True)
annual_SW = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                null=True)
annual_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                   null=True)
back_maintenance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'),
                                       blank=True )
forecast_year0 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_year1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_year2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_year3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_year4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_year5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'), blank=True,
                                     null=True)
forecast_total_0to3_years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'),
                                                blank=True )
forecast_total_0to5_years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5, default=Decimal('0.00000'),
                                                blank=True )

def __str__(self):
    return "Instance Number =" + str(self.party.item_instance_number)
```

Comment: assuming u change the database on the settings.py, could you generate the sql output? `python manage.py sql`

Comment: says unknown command 'sql'

Comment: sorry, `sqlmigrate`
 I meant

Comment: yes it gives me the sql to create tables

Comment: so now you can run the commands individually to see where it is failing

Comment: it breaks at this line: CREATE TABLE "FORECAST_APP_FORECASTSUMMARY" ("ID" NUMBER(11) GENERATED BY DEFAUL
T ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY with the error mentioned above

Comment: could you show your DATABASE settings on the settings.py?(remove your password, user and host)

Comment: edited the question with my database setting

Comment: could you share your model?

Comment: added the corresponding model

Comment: Are you sure the server is 12c, not just your client? What does select * from product_component_version or select * from v$version report?  Also, which version of Django and cx_Oracle (and Python).

Comment: the server is 11g the client is 12c, what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I tryed your CREATE TABLE statement on my 12.2.0.1 database and it worked. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806412/sql-error-ora-02000-missing-always-keyword-when-create-identity-column-based-t). May be your either use a cx_oracle version that explicitly supports your Oracle DB version or you upgrade your database to Oracle 12.