# auto increment a column value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, auto-increment

i wanted to create a table with the property that auto increment the primary key id column value but could not. how do i do that in oracle sql.how to use the identity column value.

Comment: i am using sql developer to work with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11296469/599528

Comment: For **12c**, read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/ and for **prior 12c** releases, read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/