# How to add auto increment coloumn in Oracle and access with java?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g, auto-increment

I already have table, how to add new auto increment column. by using sequence or trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You could use annotation in the Entity like:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PK", sequenceName = "SQN_TABLENAME", allocationSize = 1)
```

or add a trigger:

[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing table and wants to add new column then add new column using ALTER Query

> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (id varchar2(45));

then create one sequence for auto increment values

*

> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name
>    MINVALUE 1
>    MAXVALUE
>   999999999999999999999999999
>    START WITH 1
>    INCREMENT BY
>   1
>    CACHE 20;

*

create trigger to add values after new record is inserted into table

> create or replace trigger trg_name before insert on table_name for
>   each row    begin
>        select seq_name.nextval into :new.idfrom dual; end;

now you will able to add new id auto. into table :)

Note: do not set NOTNULL true for this column, else you will face problem while returning result set in java

hope this will help you :)