# Unable to fix SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment, alter

I am trying to learn SQL for a job interview on Tuesday. So I made a basic "People" table to get started. I then realized that you could auto increment columns. So now I need add the auto increment feature to my already existing table. I looked up how to do it but I keep getting an error message no matter how I try to do it. The table I made was like this...

```
create table People(
Person_id varchar2(3),
First_Name varchar2(30),
Last_Name varchar2(30),
Phone_Number number(10),
Email_Address varchar2(50),
Street_Address varchar2(50),
City_Name varchar(50),
State_Name varchar2(20),
Zip_Code number(10),
Occupation varchar(30),
Yearly_Pay number(20)
)
```

And I am trying to add the Auto_Increment functionality by saying something like...

```
ALTER TABLE `People`
    CHANGE COLUMN `Person_id` `Person_id` varchar2(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tb4A.jpg) is the error message I am getting.

Comment: (1) SQL Server uses `identity` columns for auto incrementing columns.  (2) Identity columns need to be numbers (integers).

Comment: *Syntax* says code is `MYSQL` and *TAG* says code is `SQL SERVER` and *error link* says code is `ORACLE.` Which one are you really using

Comment: If you want to do this in `SQL SERVER` then, You cannot alter a existing column to add `identity`

Comment: I thought they were all the same, I'm using ORACLE. The link is my own monitor.

Comment: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: No, Not at all. They all are different

Comment: @Heiland Nope. Though a good portion of the syntax is common among them, each SQL system has its own extensions of the language.

Comment: So there's no nice way of auto incrementing in oracle?