# ERROR ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE MURID2 (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  IDMURID VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  NAMA VARCHAR2(30),
  NO_HP NUMBER,
  ALAMAT VARCHAR2(30),
  IDKELAS VARCHAR2(6),
  CONSTRAINT PK_MURID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Why do I have the error **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**?

Comment: Its syntax seems to MySQL.

Comment: varchar instead of varchar2 and numeric instead of number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first if this is oracle remove  **AUTO_INCREMENT**. this is not suppoerted in oracle.

if this is mysql, replace **VARCHAR2** with **varchar** and

replace following line

```
NO_HP NUMBER,
```

with

```
NO_HP NUMBER(10),
```

Comment: maybe my oracle remove auto_increment. how to solve this?

Comment: as far i know oracle does not have auto_increment facility. you have to create a function or trigger to do it.

Comment: check the following link how to do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle