# ( Hibernate Oracle cannot insert NULL ) How to insert auto generated ID?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am working on project where I am using hibernate to perform CRUD operations. I have user model and I am trying to insert the information but keeping getting this error

```
Hibernate: insert into APPUSER (dob, email, firstName, lastName, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Jun 21, 2016 2:17:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
Jun 21, 2016 2:17:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYAPP8785"."APPUSER"."ID")
```

The user model looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APPUSER")
public class AppUser {


    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Email
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String dob;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
}
```

Hibernate properties  like

```
properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
//properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
```

I am under the impression that hibernate would auto generate id for me and insert them using sequence

Comment: What version of Oracle you are using using?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g

Comment: If you want to use a sequence for id generation, you have to configure that in your annotation (GenerationType.SEQUENCE). Oracle doesn't support identity columns, so your current id generation configuration has no effect.

Comment: Also, using MySQLDialect with Oracle makes little sense. Use the appropriate dialect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some errors :

- Use the right dialect : `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` (no specific dialect for 11g).
- do not use primitive type for hibernate generated ID (use `Integer`, not `int`)

`IDENTITY` for ID generation is supported by oracle only since [version 12c](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/)

You should use another strategy, like using sequence for example.

The mapping would look like :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "ID_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: Oracle version installed on a server I'm using is 11g. So as mentioned in the answer i used the Sequence generation strategy. I tried using TABLE and AUTO strategies as well. However, when i try to insert a record onto the table, it tells me that ID cannot be null. Shouldn't the ID be auto generated? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you found a usable answer, but since I had this same problem and came across this post while searching for a solution, I will include what worked for me. I am using Oracle 12c - and this will ONLY work with 12c - the solution was to change the dialect to Oracle12cDialect.  Otherwise, simply using

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table `APPUSER` such that its primary key `ID` has auto increment feature. Please follow the link [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle) on how to do it. Only then you will see that hibernate will insert the value in the primary key field for you.