# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis ..i got this error

Tags: oracle10g

```
create table user
(
id number(10) auto_increment,
firstName varchar(100),
lastName varchar(100),
password varchar(100),
primary key(id)
);
```

I am getting this error while creating table user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: Oracle doesn't support auto_increment (until 12c anyway), and your primary key creation syntax is wrong too. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11296361/266304).