# Auto sequence incrementer at database

Tags: java, oracle10g

I'm new to programming, so need little help from you guys.

I created a simple registration from in HTML controlled by servlet using oracle.
Whenever i submit my record, it gets stored perfectly in database, but I have assigned ID for every stored record which is not appearing to be increment in ascending order even after assigning primary key to ID.

Comment: Are you looking to auto generate id in database, or in your code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no short way to auto increment id in database itself. This post describes good way to do it in oracle.

[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Use a database sequence. And increment it by 1 every time you take a new value from that DB sequence.

Comment: Can you please in detail .