# EntityFramework & Oracle - How to get inserted Id?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I am using generic entity framework repository pattern for my oracle database.

```
public int Add(TEntity entity)
{
      var addedEntity = _context.Entry(entity);
      addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
      return _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Simply, how can I get my entity Id after that is inserted to database with generated id.

Edit: I am using oracle 11g. So there is no 'identity' keyword. I created sequences for getting max ref and trigger it before inserting. So, the entity which is I send to EF not updating after SaveChanges();

Thanks...

Comment: For Oracle you will need to get the next sequence value and use that as the Id.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Can you explain it a little bit more or can I get a resource link ?

Comment: This this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383057/193634

Comment: @RosdiKasim Is there any way to get rid of raw sql ? Is EF support to call squence with a method ?

Comment: `addedEntity.Id` after `_context.SaveChanges();`?

Answer (score 1):

For your identity-Column you have to set the property `<storeGeneratedPattern>` to `<Identity>` in the EF Model-Browser.

1. Go to your entity in the Model Browser

   [image]
2. Set property

   [image]

This will get the current, new value for your ID-Column after your identity has been saved.

Works for me with ORACLE, EF-Framework 6