# Oracle 11g: add a column to an EXISTING table with auto increment long value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I have a table, say Name, (I simplify the example for simplicity). This table already exists, and has data. Now, I need to add an ID column of type long to it, and need to make the value auto incremented.

For Oracle 12c, this is easy with *generated always as identity*.

However, I work on Oracle 11g, and such a feature is not supported. So I needed to create a trigger, as described in this post: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

```
alter table name add (id integer);

create sequence name_seq;

create or replace trigger name_bir;   
before insert on name
for each row
begin
 select name_seq.NEXTVAL
 into :new.id
 from dual;
end;
```

However, that solution (creating a sequence, and then a trigger on Insert/Update) only works when a new row is inserted. It doesn't apply to the existing rows in the table.

I'd appreciate any suggestion. Basically, I need BOTH the **existing** and the **newly-inserted** rows to have the new ID values for my newly added column ID.

=============================

Solution (collected from the answer):

1. Use "update" statement as posted by "a_horse_with_no_name" to update the existing rows
2. Still need a trigger above for any new rows that will be inserted.

Comment: Create a `#table_seq` and just write a query that will `loop` through `#table` by adding `#table_seq.nexval` to `id` column

Comment: you meant, I need both the trigger (for the newly inserted rows), and the loop (for the existing rows), correct?

Comment: You don't need any trigger. Just use `#table_seq.nextval` while inserting new row

Comment: I am not well familiar with PL/SQL. Can you give the syntax example?

Comment: @kzharas210: there is no need for a slow loop in PL/SQL to update the existing rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you created the sequence, just update the existing rows:

```
alter table name add (id integer);

create sequence name_seq;

update name 
  set id = name_seq.nextval;
commit;
```

There is no need for PL/SQL or a slow and in-efficient row-by-row processing in a LOOP.

---

Unrelated, but: the assignment in the trigger can be simplified to:

```
:new.id := name_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

No need for a `select .. from dual`

Answer (score -1):

After adding the ID column and creating the NAME_SEQ sequence as you have mentioned, rather that using loop, an easier option would be to use Update statement as follows:

```
update NAME set ID= NAME_SEQ.nextval ;
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick

```
BEGIN
alter table name add (id integer);
create sequence name_seq;

FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM NAME) LOOP
UPDATE NAME SET ID = NAME_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
WHERE ROWID = REC.ROWID;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Do you even require loop? Cant it be done using simple update clause?

Comment: @VimalBhaskar: no loop required, see my answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i haved check that bro. It was quite clear. Hence i gave the up vote :)