# Field autoincrement for Oracle without trigger with Slick?

Tags: oracle, scala, slick

I am trying to insert rows in a ErrorTable which has a few fields plus an idError which is supossed to be the primary key.  I need idError to be autoincremented. However one requirement is we cannot use a trigger, so using O.AutoInc would not work for us.

We also tried to use plain sql using a sequence. However we have two blob fields which makes the query too long ( getting the string literal too long error).

Any idea about how to attack this problem? I am also considering to use UUID.

Note: we are using oracle-xe-11g

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on? Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle), specifically the points about identity columns in 12c.

Comment: We are using oracle-xe-11g

Answer (score 2):

In 11g you can have only implement an auto-incrementing identifier with a trigger. So it seems your requirements rule out anything except SYS_GUID. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions175.htm#SQLRF06120).

> " it also represents another query to get that value "

Not necessarily. If you have the option to define the target table you can set a default values for the UUID column like this:

```
 create table t23 (
      id raw(16) default sys_guid() not null primary key
      , col1 varchar2(10)          
);
```

Then

```
SQL>  insert into t23 (col1) values ('ABC');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t23;

ID                               COL1
-------------------------------- -----------
7DD7216E731C126537615FE1244B4B50 ABC

SQL>
```

Note: tested on 12C but should work in earlier versions.

Comment: It seems a good option, but it also represents another query to get that value (as querying for the next val before inserting) or inserting it in a plain query (coming back to the "string literal too long" problem). But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Again, your answer is awesome! But when i said that it represents another query, it was in my context, because i can't make a plain query because the "string literal too long problem" and i am not sure how to do that query with Slick in another way. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know Slick, but it seems like that library is your problem.