# ORA-24344 on 'auto increment'

Tags: oracle, auto-increment, oracle-call-interface, adodb-php

I try to imitate the auto increment functionality in oracle as explained here:
[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle). However, when I try to call the second statement, the trigger, I always get an `ORA-24344: success with compilation error` and the trigger does not kick in. What can I do?

I call the statements via php/adodb

As you can see, I do not use any newlines in my code. Removing newlines was suggested in other threads.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE abc_autoinc START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER abc_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON abc FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN SELECT abc_autoinc.NEXTVAL INTO :new.abc_id  FROM dual; END
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Can't you see the compilation errors? What client are you using to run this query?

Comment: yes, that is the complete error message. I run it via php/adodb

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an `;` after `END`. Now it works!