# Asp.NET entity Framework. How to automatically generate primary key?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Problem :

- If I make STOREGENERATED PATTERN = NONE   Record is inserted in my database once with ID =0. After that it gives error so I change it to identity

  [image]
- I wanted to automatically generate primary key. I created a new project made it Identity

  ```
    public partial class USER
  {
  [key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string NAME { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(USER obj)
    {
       using( var db = new Entities() )
       {
           var u = new USER();
           u.NAME = obj.NAME;
           db.USERS.Add(u);
           db.SaveChanges();
       }

        return View();
    }
```

ERROR!

[image]

I search on the internet but could not make it work.
 --> I want my project to automatically create Primary key of tables. I am using Oracle SQL database and Entity framework 5.0.0

Comment: how can I tell oracle? 
the data is indeed inserted in Oracle once if I make store generated pattern to NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the EDMX, but that's just a model of your database. It doesn't change the database by itself.

Configure the column so it actually is generated by the server: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle).