# No row selected

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

```
SQL> create table artwork
  2         (
      artwork_id number(7) NOT NULL,
       barcode char(20),
        title char(20),
        description char(50),
      PRIMARY KEY (artwork_id)
      );  

Table created.


SQL> select * from artwork;

no rows selected
```

I created the table but it showing me this error  dont know. Why table it not showing?

Comment: you create a table and doesn't `INSERT` rows. So your `SELECT` can't select rows of your table. You can insert a row with a `INSERT` statement (`INSERT INTO artwork VALUES (...)`).

Comment: What are these numbers? 2  3  4  5  6  7  8

Comment: You haven't inserted any to be selected.  INSERT INTO artwork (artwork_id, barcode, title, description) values (1, '', '', '');

Comment: ok got it have one more query  `SQL> create table artist
  2         (
      artist_id number(7) NOT NULL,
       name varchar(20),
        address varchar(20),
        contact_number int(10),
      PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)
      );  3    4    5    6    7    8
        contact_number int(10),
                          *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL? Or Oracle? ORA is usually Oracle server.

Comment: Well you never inserted rows, how do you expect the table to magically contain rows? There is no error in your question

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the `create` to look like this:

```
create table artwork (
    artwork_id number primary key,
    barcode char(20),
    title varchar2(20),
    description varchar2(50)
);
```

Notes:

- There is no need to have `number(7)`.  You can specify the length, but it is not necessary.
- For `title` and `description` you definitely want `varchar2()`.  There is no reason to store trailing spaces at the end of a name.
- That may be the same for `barcode`, but because it might always be exactly 20 characters or trailing spaces might be significant, you might leave it as `char()`.
- The `primary key` constraint can be expressed in-line.  There is no need for a separate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply want something like

```
create table artwork
(
  artwork_id number(7) NOT NULL,
  barcode varchar2(20),
  title varchar2(20),
  description varchar2(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (artwork_id)
);

insert into artwork values (0, 'barcode', 'fancytitle', 'somedescription');
insert into artwork values (1, 'barcode1', 'fancytitle1', 'somedescription1');

select * from artwork;
```

This creates a table "ARTWORK", inserts 2 rows in it and then selects all rows currently in the table.

An empty table contains no data, with the `create table`-statement you only define the bucket of data, you have to fill the bucket as well with items.

I'd also recommend [a auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle) column (oracle 12c) or a trigger/sequence to increment the id automatically. But that's something to read later :)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with sqlplus, I usually use sqldeveloper. I edited it. Thanks