# Unable to add in code for assigning and printing unique id in alert message in registration for each register

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to assign a unique id for each registration attempt by users and display that unique ID based on first name and last name after completion of registration...Here are my incomplete sets of codes.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$regno=$_POST['regno'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$mname=$_POST['mname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$contactno=$_POST['contact'];
$emailid=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];   
$query="insert into           
userRegistration

 (regNo,firstName,middleName,lastName,gender,contactNo,email,pas
  sword) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
 $rc=$stmt->bind_param
 ('sssssiss',$regno,$fname,$mname,$lname,$gender,$contactno,$emailid,$ 
  password);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo"<script>alert('Registration successfully done');</script>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you try Auto-increment parameter for unique id yet?

Comment: not yet.......please add if possible that works..actually i'm unable to print value stored in variable in the alert box

Comment: This can help with auto-increment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/

Comment: sorry but i want implementation in php not in oracle

Comment: @SameerPrasad This is handled in mysql. Look at the question Saharsh linked and the answer explains how to do what you are after.

Comment: @hdifen cud you please add to this set of codes and post ......and what changes is required in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to try and create a unique id with only PHP you could try some old school md5

```
   $uuid = md5($emailid);
   OR
   $uuid = md5($fname . $lname .$emailid);
```

as requested

```
    $emailid = 'joe@dirt.com';
    $uuid = md5($emailid);
    echo "<script>alert('Your ID is: $uuid');</script>";
```

Comment: how to print that value of $uuid in alertbox using php

Comment: Thanx @justin hughes