# Dynamically passing Contract_id in the plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here I am updating for one particular `contract_id`.
I need to update for all `contract_ids` at one shot,
i.e Dynamically passing Contract_id in the plsql block.

```
DECLARE
    VAR1   NUMBER := 0;

    CURSOR C1 (P_CONTRACT_ID IN NUMBER)
    IS
        SELECT GO.CONTRACT_ID,
               GO.COLUMN46,
               GO.COLUMN1,
               GO.ORG_ID
          FROM XYZ GO
         WHERE GO.CONTRACT_ID = P_CONTRACT_ID AND GO.COLUMN46 IS NULL;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT NVL (MAX (TO_NUMBER (COLUMN46)), 0)
          INTO VAR1
          FROM XYZ
         WHERE CONTRACT_ID = 525215;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            VAR1 := 0;
    END;

    FOR F1 IN C1 (525215)
    LOOP
        VAR1 := VAR1 + 1;

        BEGIN
            UPDATE XYZ
               SET COLUMN46 = VAR1
             WHERE     CONTRACT_ID = F1.CONTRACT_ID
                   AND COLUMN46 IS NULL
                   AND COLUMN1 = F1.COLUMN1;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                NULL;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        NULL;
END;
```

Comment: You should really remove all of those `WHEN OTHERS` logic bombs. What if the first lookup fails because of a corrupted index block? I've seen that happen. Do you really want it to just set `VAR1 := 0;` and carry on as if everything was fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your cursor and remove your where-condition:

```
CURSOR C1
IS
    SELECT GO.CONTRACT_ID,
           GO.COLUMN46,
           GO.COLUMN1,
           GO.ORG_ID
      FROM XYZ GO
     WHERE GO.COLUMN46 IS NULL;
```

You properbly want to remove it at id-select, too:

```
    SELECT NVL (MAX (TO_NUMBER (COLUMN46)), 0)
      INTO VAR1
      FROM XYZ
     --WHERE CONTRACT_ID = 525215
     ;
```

You should also read something about sequences and triggers to generate Ids ;-)
[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: IT IS UPDATING FOR ALL THE CONTRACT_ID'S IN SINGLE SEQUENCE

Comment: 511522 1
511522 2
511522 3
511522 4
560853 5
511522 6
511522 7
560853 8
560853 9
560853 10
560853 11

Comment: So you want to change the "525215" dynamically? Btw. how about deactivating caps lock ;)