# Adding AUTO_INCREMENT using ALTER in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g, auto-increment, alter-table

I've been trying to add **AUTO_INCREMENT** on a created table , but the ALTER table query is not working

My Table:
[image: My Table Description]

Query and Error:
[image]

And also

```
ALTER TABLE professor ADD sno INT IDENTITY;
```

is not working

Comment: so whats the workaround for 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try:

```
alter table professor add sno integer generated by default on null as identity;
```

EDIT: Sorry, the OP is asking for 11g, as the code above works after 12.

Then you need to use sequence. Please see below:

```
ALTER TABLE professor ADD sno INT;
CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq START WITH 1;
```

And you need to set a trigger for your sequence like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON departments 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

Reference: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: didn't work, it says 'missing ALWAYS keyword'

Comment: ok i will check this, but is there no easy solution for this like just adding any keyword or something?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Unfortunately, not