# How to modify column to auto increment in PL SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl, identity-column

I have created one table in PL SQL Developer.

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_List
(
   Patient_ID number NOT NULL,
   Patient_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   Patient_Address varchar(100) NULL,
   App_Date date NULL,
   Descr varchar(50),
   CONSTRAINT patient_pk PRIMARY KEY(Patient_ID)
);
```

I want to auto increment Patient_ID, I tried altering the table and modifying the Patient_ID column but it's showing an error "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

```
ALTER TABLE Patient_List
MODIFY Patient_ID NUMBER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? (`SELECT version 
FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
where product like 'Oracle%';` will tell you)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 10.2.0.5.0

Comment: Identity columns were introduced in Oracle 12.1 (and even there you can't change an existing column to an identity column - you can only modify exiting identity columns or **add** a new identity column)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, thanks.

Comment: as a_horse_with_no_name said you cannot use identity colum unless your version is 12.
You can creat a `sequence` and write `trigger` to insert values automatically or access sequence from your code
and set it as the value to `Patient_ID `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Oracle 10g didn't even have identity columns, they were introduced in Oracle 12.1

But even with a current Oracle version, you can't convert a regular column to an identity column. You would need to add a new one.

Before identity columns, the usual way was to create a sequence and a trigger to populate the column.

See here: [How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361)

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants to modify existing column as auto_increment use this three lines

```
alter table Product drop column test_id;

create sequence Product_test_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 nocache;

alter table Product add test_id Number default Product_test_id_seq.nextval not null;
```