# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis (While Creating the Table)

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I am facing the issue while creating the Table in `SQL`,

```
CREATE TABLE Worker 
(
    WORKER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(25),
    LAST_NAME CHAR(25),
    SALARY INT(15),
    JOINING_DATE DATETIME,
    DEPARTMENT CHAR(25)
);
```

Facing the Error

> "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Can you please help with this.
I have modified the query and re-run it various times still getting this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle). You appear to be using MySQL syntax in Oracle

Comment: AFIK Oracle up to 11 there may no concept like `AUTO_INCREMENT` You need to use `SEQUENCE`. So which version you use?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: do not use the `char` data type it has a lot of disadvantages but no advantages whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is not the keyword in Oracle and no such concept is available in oracle till oracle 12c.

In **oracle 12c**, The new concept is introduced, which is `IDENTITY` Columns.

Also, DATETIME is not a valid data type in oracle. see inline comments in the following example.

You can create the desired table as following in your case (**Oracle 12 or higher**):

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE Worker
>   2  (
>   3     WORKER_ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
>   4     FIRST_NAME CHAR(25),
>   5     LAST_NAME CHAR(25),
>   6     SALARY INT,
>   7     -- JOINING_DATE DATETIME, datetime is not a data type in oracle
>   8     JOINING_DATE DATE, -- date stores date and time both the component
>   9     DEPARTMENT CHAR(25)
>  10  );
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Still facing the issue, "Right Parantesis Missing"

Comment: Paste the exact code which you are executing. And also share your oracle version.