# How to add an auto increment primary key to a table already loaded with data in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Tried this several time, just wanted to know if there is a workaround

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle) answer your question ?

Comment: It's not clear from you question if you are adding a new column that you need to populate, or if you have an existing column with existing data, and you want to start using auto increment for all future data.  The correct solution will depend on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `identity` column in this case as follows:

```
alter table test 
add col1 number generated always as  identity (start with 1 increment by 1)
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a977efc1b3d9ec2050dc8fda286f62c)

It will automatically assign the `sequence` number to the already existing rows and will give number in `sequence` to new inserts also.

Comment: Can you suggest something for 11g as well? Would the solution be to create a squence? Will it assign a number to the existing rows?