# Oracle SQL Create Table Says Missing Parenthesis? Can't see it

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm trying to create a certain table but I get this error from Oracle:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I tried to look it up but found nothing similar...

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
    NAME VERCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(12) CHECK(PHONE_NUMBER LIKE '%%%-%%%-%%%%') NOT NULL, 
    SALARY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    SENIORITY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

Comment: `VERCHAR2` is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. As @GordonLinoff pointed out in the comments, `VERCHAR2` is a typo and should be changed to `VARCHAR2`;
2. As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out in his (now deleted) answer, your `CHECK` constraint allows for any value that has two hyphen's in it (e.g. `x-y-z`) to be inserted into the phone number. You should use something like what he suggested i.e.
   `REGEXP_LIKE(PHONE_NUMBER, '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')`
3. Finally, and the actual reason for the error, the `NOT NULL` declaration on `EMPLOYEE_ID` should be *after* the `GENERATED` clause, not before it. Note you might actually want
   `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY`
   to insert an identity value if `NULL` is inserted (instead of generating an error as your current definition will)

Your query should be:

```sql
create table Employees
(
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(12) CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(PHONE_NUMBER, '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')) NOT NULL, 
SALARY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
SENIORITY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

Here's a [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1cb064da3f269ced7965e36f689264c4) which also shows the effect of using `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY` instead of `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL`.

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting the same error code

Comment: @ErezAvior which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: `IDENTITY` columns didn't exist before 12c. You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: Ok so I tried to do it like that:
```
create table Employees
(
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(12) CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(PHONE_NUMBER, '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')) NOT NULL, 
SALARY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
SENIORITY NUMBER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE Employees ADD (
  CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID));

CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq START WITH 1;
```
And the error jumped:
`ORA-00911: invalid character`

Comment: You should probably ask a new question. That works fine in 11g (although you don't need the `ALTER TABLE` command as you already declare a primary key) but I don't have access to a 10g version to test it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f4823397f105e6dd8c8827d7c387be3