# ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have an entity class `Content` and I'm using a sequence generator to generate the id automatically.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTENT")
public class Content {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "SEQ_C")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_C", sequenceName = "SEQ_INCREMENTER_CONTENT", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
}
```

I'm inserting data with a `saveAll()` using spring boot JPA.

```
contentRepository.saveAll(contents);
```

I'm generating the table using `liquibase`.

```
<createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_INCREMENTER_CONTENT" cycle="false" minValue="1" startValue="1" incrementBy="1"/>
<createTable tableName="content">
        <column defaultValueSequenceNext="SEQ_INCREMENTER_CONTENT" name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_content"/>
    </column>
    <column name="content_type" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
    <column name="content_type_id" type="INT"/>
    <column name="data" type="VARCHAR2(255)"/>
    <column name="placement" type="INT"/>
    <column name="placement_id" type="INT"/>
    <column name="segment_id" type="BIGINT"/>
</createTable>
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="segment_id" baseTableName="content" constraintName="FK_CONTENT_ON_SEGMENT" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="segment"/>
```

When I insert the data, spring boot JPA gives me the following error.

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here
```

Also, I tried the other generation strategies as `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, `GenerationType.AUTO` and `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. Still, I'm having the issue. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on version 11 or lower, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle/11296469#11296469)

If DB-version is 12 or above you may use identity column feature as [described here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/416)

This is how you can check DB-version you're on

```
select version
  from v$instance;
```

or

```
select *
  from v$version;
```

Comment: "*Using sequences is not allowed in oracle's default column setting*" - yes it is, since 12.2 (so for all supported versions)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name never knew that. thanks! Will update my answer shortly