# (ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis) where is error in my code?

Tags: sql, oracle

CREATE TABLE student(
student_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
major VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);
why is it saying (ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis)

Comment: Oracle doesn't have`auto_increment`. Use `generated always|by default as identity`

Answer (score 1):

If your Oracle database version supports it (12c or higher), use the **identity** column:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student
  2    (student_id int generated always as identity,
  3     name       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  4     major      VARCHAR(20),
  5     PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

You don't have to specify `not null` constraint for primary key columns; they can't be `null` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has no `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Take a look at this question for how to deal with that.

[How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)