# Facing issue while adding new column as auto increment

Tags: oracle

I am facing issue while adding new column as auto increment in existing table.

When I use this command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE NCS.generic_usg_data_store_dum ADD id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key;
```

getting an error like below:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
```

Anyone please assist me on this

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [`ALTER TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you used **wrong syntax** for `alter table`.

Here's correct one:

```
SQL> create table test_so
  2    (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> alter table test_so add id int generated always as identity primary key;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

As you commented that such a statement won't work, it appears that your Oracle database version doesn't support identity columns. In that case, you'll have to do that with a database trigger. Here's how:

```
SQL> create table test_so
  2    (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> alter table test_so add id int;

Table altered.

SQL> create sequence seq_so;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test_so
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.id is null)
  5  begin
  6    :new.id := seq_so.nextval;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test_so (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_so;

NAME                         ID
-------------------- ----------
Littlefoot                    1

SQL>
```

Comment: if i use this command:- alter table tablename add id int generated always as identity primary key; getting error like :-Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

Comment: @PoojaKaranam please confirm your version of Oracle Database

Comment: Right; looks like your database version doesn't support identity columns. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: the version is 8

Comment: That's really old version (consider upgrading your database). In that case, **trigger** it is.

Comment: 8?? Literally laugh out loud. your database is 26 years old!!!